# Python "multiplatform" push library with longevity

Tags: python, push-notification

For about a year I was running scripts that were sending me email from all kinds of operating systems and also pypy in addition to standard Pythons in OS/X etc. This came to a perhaps temporary end with the tightening of email security in the SMTP providers I was using and the given setups of SSL etc, sometimes in weird parts of the OS. I am OK with sending a push notification out instead, even to FB Messenger, but I would like to survive longer than a year this time. Not to mention that my first go at "fbchat" gave me some errors in pypy3. Any ideas what I should push and where? I saw some (millions) people use the Google/Android push infrastructure but I can almost guarantee it will cost me some lost messages with the way they are known to tighten their security, request new verifications etc. How hard can it be to send and receive a notification :) Set and forget! PS I do not particularly need it encrypted and such.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read this -- How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example -- https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to abstract away the changing APIs with an umbrella API like amio.io. Their free tier is enough to establish a few so-called "channels", ie authorize push to other platforms, and they will be taking care of most of the channel management while you will be pushing with one API.